# Does fitting data get stuck by non-homogeneous interval of data?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, fitting

We have a list which is considered to be fitted by a suitable function. The list is given at the end of the text. It maybe important to mention that the first column of the list is not in the same interval I mean:

```
list[[All, 1]][[1 ;; 50]] has an interval of 2*10^-6
list[[All, 1]][[51 ;; 150]] has an interval of 10^-5
```

We have exploited of

```
nlf=NonlinearModelFit[list, a Exp[b g] + c, {a, {b, -1}, c},
g]
```

But we encountered the message: "*Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations*."

How can we overcome this problem? Does the problem arise of the not same interval of the first column of data?

```
list={{0., 0.499999}, {2.*10^-7, 0.499311}, {4.*10^-7, 
0.499025}, {6.*10^-7, 0.498806}, {8.*10^-7, 0.498621}, {1.*10^-6, 
0.498459}, {1.2*10^-6, 0.498311}, {1.4*10^-6, 0.498176}, {1.6*10^-6,
 0.49805}, {1.8*10^-6, 0.497931}, {2.*10^-6, 0.497819}, {2.2*10^-6, 
0.497713}, {2.4*10^-6, 0.497611}, {2.6*10^-6, 0.497513}, {2.8*10^-6,
0.497419}, {3.*10^-6, 0.497328}, {3.2*10^-6, 0.49724}, {3.4*10^-6, 
0.497155}, {3.6*10^-6, 0.497072}, {3.8*10^-6, 0.496992}, {4.*10^-6, 
0.496914}, {4.2*10^-6, 0.496837}, {4.4*10^-6, 0.496752}, {4.6*10^-6,
0.496679}, {4.8*10^-6, 0.496607}, {5.*10^-6, 0.496537}, {5.2*10^-6,
0.496468}, {5.4*10^-6, 0.4964}, {5.6*10^-6, 0.496334}, {5.8*10^-6, 
0.496268}, {6.*10^-6, 0.496204}, {6.2*10^-6, 0.496141}, {6.4*10^-6, 
0.496079}, {6.6*10^-6, 0.496017}, {6.8*10^-6, 0.495957}, {7.*10^-6, 
0.495898}, {7.2*10^-6, 0.495839}, {7.4*10^-6, 0.495781}, {7.6*10^-6,
0.495724}, {7.8*10^-6, 0.495668}, {8.*10^-6, 0.495612}, {8.2*10^-6,
0.495557}, {8.4*10^-6, 0.495503}, {8.6*10^-6, 
0.495449}, {8.8*10^-6, 0.495396}, {9.*10^-6, 0.495344}, {9.2*10^-6, 
0.495292}, {9.4*10^-6, 0.495241}, {9.6*10^-6, 0.49519}, {9.8*10^-6, 
0.49514}, {0.00001, 0.49509}, {0.000011, 0.494848}, {0.000021, 
0.492857}, {0.000031, 0.491298}, {0.000041, 0.48997}, {0.000051, 
0.488791}, {0.000061, 0.487719}, {0.000071, 0.486728}, {0.000081, 
0.485803}, {0.000091, 0.48493}, {0.000101, 0.484102}, {0.000111, 
0.483312}, {0.000121, 0.482555}, {0.000131, 0.481827}, {0.000141, 
0.481125}, {0.000151, 0.480446}, {0.000161, 0.479788}, {0.000171, 
0.479148}, {0.000181, 0.478526}, {0.000191, 0.477919}, {0.000201, 
0.477328}, {0.000211, 0.476749}, {0.000221, 0.476184}, {0.000231, 
0.47563}, {0.000241, 0.475087}, {0.000251, 0.474555}, {0.000261, 
0.474032}, {0.000271, 0.473518}, {0.000281, 0.473013}, {0.000291, 
0.472516}, {0.000301, 0.472027}, {0.000311, 0.471545}, {0.000321, 
0.471071}, {0.000331, 0.470603}, {0.000341, 0.470141}, {0.000351, 
0.469686}, {0.000361, 0.469236}, {0.000371, 0.468792}, {0.000381, 
0.468354}, {0.000391, 0.467921}, {0.000401, 0.467492}, {0.000411, 
0.467069}, {0.000421, 0.46665}, {0.000431, 0.466236}, {0.000441, 
0.465826}, {0.000451, 0.46542}, {0.000461, 0.465018}, {0.000471, 
0.46462}, {0.000481, 0.464226}, {0.000491, 0.463836}, {0.000501, 
0.463449}, {0.000511, 0.463066}, {0.000521, 0.462685}, {0.000531, 
0.462309}, {0.000541, 0.461935}, {0.000551, 0.461564}, {0.000561, 
0.461197}, {0.000571, 0.460832}, {0.000581, 0.46047}, {0.000591, 
0.460111}, {0.000601, 0.459755}, {0.000611, 0.459401}, {0.000621, 
0.45905}, {0.000631, 0.458701}, {0.000641, 0.458355}, {0.000651, 
0.458011}, {0.000661, 0.45767}, {0.000671, 0.457331}, {0.000681, 
0.456994}, {0.000691, 0.456659}, {0.000701, 0.456326}, {0.000711, 
0.455996}, {0.000721, 0.455667}, {0.000731, 0.45534}, {0.000741, 
0.455016}, {0.000751, 0.454693}, {0.000761, 0.454373}, {0.000771, 
0.454054}, {0.000781, 0.453737}, {0.000791, 0.453421}, {0.000801, 
0.453108}, {0.000811, 0.452796}, {0.000821, 0.452486}, {0.000831, 
0.452177}, {0.000841, 0.45187}, {0.000851, 0.451565}, {0.000861, 
0.451261}, {0.000871, 0.450959}, {0.000881, 0.450658}, {0.000891, 
0.450359}, {0.000901, 0.450061}, {0.000911, 0.449765}, {0.000921, 
0.44947}, {0.000931, 0.449177}, {0.000941, 0.448885}, {0.000951, 
0.448594}, {0.000961, 0.448304}, {0.000971, 0.448016}, {0.000981, 
0.44773}, {0.000991, 0.447444}};
```

Comment: The simple answer is "No, that's not why it's getting stuck."  It's getting stuck because the model is not appropriate for the data (even though that error message goes away when the option `MaxIterations -> 2000` is included.  You might want to try `a - b g^0.5` for the model.

Comment: Very amazing. I thought Exp can fit the data!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the question:

> Does fitting data get stuck by non-homogeneous interval of data?

and OP's comment:

> I thought Exp can fit the data!!

I would say the situation could have been quickly diagnosed with `FindFormula`:

```
ff = FindFormula[list]

(* 0.497329 - 150.254 #1 + 306909. #1^2 - 3.56245*10^8 #1^3 + 1.5053*10^11 #1^4 & *)

ListPlot[{list, {#, ff[#]} & /@ list[[All, 1]]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotLegends -> {"data", "fit"}]
```

[image]

*See [Jim Baldwin's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147033/34008) for more detailed analysis.*

Answer (score 2):

The irregular spacing of the data has nothing to do with it.  You could eliminate the warning by just using `MaxIterations=2000` but that wouldn't fix the problem that the functional form you're using gives a poor fit.

```
nlf = NonlinearModelFit[list, a Exp[b g] + c, {a, {b, -1}, c}, g, MaxIterations -> 2000];
Show[ListPlot[list], Plot[nlf[g], {g, 0, 0.001}]]
```

[image: data and poor fit]

For this data a function of the form $a-b g^c$ gives a good fit.

```
nlf = NonlinearModelFit[list, a - b  If[g == 0, 0, g^c], {{a, 0.5}, {b, 2}, {c, 0.5}}, g];
nlf["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 0.49971290516938405, b -> 2.0435760088187127, c -> 0.5303297586312835} *)
Show[ListPlot[list], Plot[nlf[g], {g, 0, 0.001}]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

Note that rather than just using `g^c` I've had to use `If[g==0, 0, g^c]` because `NonlinearFit` complains with just `g^c`.  (Alternatively with this much data and low variability about the curve one could just drop the first data point where `g=0` using `list[[2;;]]` in place of `list`.  But I'm adverse to dropping data.)